# Send alert tone to pc from microcontroller via serial communication

Tags: microcontroller, pic, serial

I am learning microcontroller for couple of weeks. Yesterday, I have learned how to establish serial communication between PC and microcontroller. I can send texts to pc's hyperterminal from mcu and send text from pc to mcu.

Now, one question arises in my mind. It is how can I send control words to pc from mcu, say send an alert tone to pc from mcu? Is it possible? 
Thanks. BTW, I am using PIC microcontroller.

Comment: What do you mean by "control words"?

Comment: Yeah, for example, i want to send control word to hear a beep sound. :)

Comment: I think you are looking for the bel character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

Your terminal decides if it will in fact sound a bell, flash the screen or do noting.

Comment: If i send 07H as an ascii to hyperterminal will the bell sound occur?

Comment: @SabbirAhmed I think it will, but probably with a Windows sound. You may have to configure hyperterminal or Windows to have the bell sound. Officially terminal programs should still support those control characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a bit like a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

If you just want to produce a sound whenever your MCU detects some condition, I strongly suggest some sort of buzzer (magnetic or piezo). That's simple, reliable, energy-efficient *and* cheap. Using a computer just for this task is a huge overkill !

However, I suppose you ask the question this way because you want later on to trigger something more involved that needs your computer. The generic way to solve this problem is to write on the computer some always-on program (a *"daemon"*) that talks to your mcu through serial port (or USB or whatever) and does whatever is necessary, whenever necessary : (python example)

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
while (True) :
    if Serial.read()=='a' :
        # do something
```

You could also probably start a standard shell (bash, zsh or whatever is available for your OS) talking through serial port. You need to setup the serial port before that (stty comes to my mind) ; but then you don't need to write / maintain anything on the PC by yourself and you just write commands from your mcu on the serial TX.